# How do I mock externally injected libraries that use import (ES6 typescript) exported in a node module for unit testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

In my main app, I am bringing in the node package "ibm_db" using:
`import * as ibmdb from "ibm_db";`

In my unit tests I want to be able to override this, then I:
`import * as ibmdb from "ibm_db";`

in my unit test and then:

```
beforeEach(() => {
   ibmdb.open = jasmine.createSpy("open");
});
```

I get error:

```
Cannot assign to 'open' because it is a readOnly property.
```

I need to know with typescript (being compiled into js using tsc, then tested using jasmine command), the right way to mock these functions so I can tell if there being called, I don't want the calls to actually fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ES6 imports use:

```
import * as name from "library_name"
```

and in the unit tests use:

```
const name = require("library_name");
```

Requires will let you overwrite parts of the library where imports will not